# Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, prove $e \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ for all $n$

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to figure out to solve this problem:

> Given a graph $G = (V, E)$ prove $$e \leq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ for all $n$, where $e$ is the number of edges and $n$ is the number of vertices.

I'm thinking that I should somehow be using math induction to figure out the correct answer and use $n = 1$ or $0$ for my hypothesis, but I'm getting a little stuck on what to do after -- if I assume $n = k$, then: 
$$e \leq \frac{(k+1)k}{2}.$$ 
And if $n = k+1$ then $$e \leq \frac{k(k-1)}{2}.$$

As I understand it, each vertex has $n-1$ possible edges coming out, and there are n total vertices, which is where $n(n-1)$ comes from and dividing by $2$ gets rid of the repeats. But I am unsure how I am to prove this.

Comment: Induction hypothesis: If $G$ has $k$ vertices then it has at most $k(k-1)/2$ edges. 
Suppose if we add another vertex then it can create at most $k$ new edges. 
So the total number of edges in $k+1$ vertex graph is at most  $k+ k(k-1)/2=k(k+1)/2$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is the number of edges in a simple, complete graph with $n$ vertices, for any $n \ge 2$. This is because, in a simple, complete graph with at least 2 vertices, every *pair* of vertices has an edge between them. So there are in total $\binom{n}{2}$ edges which is equivalent to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Assuming that your graph $G$ is also a simple graph, it will be either complete or not complete. In either case, $e \le \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. For $n = 1$, check that the statement still holds.

Also, $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ is a value that you will probably encounter quite often in graph theory. It is quite helpful to remember that it represents the total number of edges in a simple, complete graph. Often it is quite a useful tool in graph theory inequality proofs.